Switching to USB headset does not work well after upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04
I use my NVIDIA GPU's sound output as main sound sink. However, from time to time, I plug in an EPOS headset (a USB dongle that wirelessly communicates to the actual headset).
Under KUbuntu 22.04, pulseaudio would automatically switch to EPOS for sound input and output.
Sinc upgrading to KUbuntu 24.04.1, this has not been working as well, and I am at a loss to debug it because I am not familiar with pipewire nor with the pipewire-pulse "bridge".
Upon plugging in the EPOS dongle, the switch does not happen correctly : in pavucontrol, EPOS is shown as the default source and sink, but there is no actual sound. I can get it to work by using pavucontrol to select NVIDIA GPU as the default, then again EPOS.
On some occasion (during a webconference), I suddenly got no more sound. I restored it by doing the same manoeuvre in pavucontrol. But it went awry again when I closed pavucontrol. This however does not happen systematically but seems random.
My configuration is, I think, pretty standard for an upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04. The only change I made is I created a symlink to /bin/true under $HOME/bin/pulseaudio : this enabled a game (Victoria 3) to correctly detect the NVIDIA GPU sound sink (it would output to the computer case's internal speaker otherwise).
FYI, the webconference was with Big Blue Button under Firefox (obtained from Mozilla directly, not the snap distrib).
Here is the beginning of the output of pactl list while the EPOS dongle is working (is there an equivalent for pipewire ?) :
Module #1
    Nom : libpipewire-module-rt
    Paramètre : {
            nice.level    = -11
            rt.prio       = 88
            #rt.time.soft = -1
            #rt.time.hard = -1
            #uclamp.min = 0
            #uclamp.max = 1024
        }
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-rt"
        object.id = "1"
        object.serial = "1"
        module.author = "Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>"
        module.description = "Use realtime thread scheduling, falling back to RTKit"
        module.usage = "( nice.level=<priority: default 20(don't change)> ) ( rt.prio=<priority: default 83> ) ( rt.time.soft=<in usec: default -1> ) ( rt.time.hard=<in usec: default -1> ) ( rlimits.enabled=<default true> ) ( rtportal.enabled=<default true> ) ( rtkit.enabled=<default true> ) ( uclamp.min=<default 0> ) ( uclamp.max=<default 1024> )"
        module.version = "1.0.5"
        nice.level = "-11"
        rt.prio = "88"

Module #2
    Nom : libpipewire-module-protocol-native
    Paramètre : {
            # List of server Unix sockets, and optionally permissions
            #sockets = [ { name = "pipewire-0" }, { name = "pipewire-0-manager" } ]
        }
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-protocol-native"
        object.id = "2"
        object.serial = "2"
        module.author = "Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>"
        module.description = "Native protocol using unix sockets"
        module.version = "1.0.5"

Module #3
    Nom : libpipewire-module-profiler
    Paramètre : 
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-profiler"
        object.id = "3"
        object.serial = "3"
        module.author = "Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>"
        module.description = "Generate Profiling data"
        module.version = "1.0.5"

Module #5
    Nom : libpipewire-module-metadata
    Paramètre : 
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-metadata"
        object.id = "5"
        object.serial = "5"
        module.author = "Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>"
        module.description = "Allow clients to create metadata store"
        module.version = "1.0.5"

Module #7
    Nom : libpipewire-module-spa-device-factory
    Paramètre : 
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-spa-device-factory"
        object.id = "7"
        object.serial = "7"
        module.author = "Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>"
        module.description = "Provide a factory to make SPA devices"
        module.version = "1.0.5"

Module #9
    Nom : libpipewire-module-spa-node-factory
    Paramètre : 
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-spa-node-factory"
        object.id = "9"
        object.serial = "9"
        module.author = "Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>"
        module.description = "Provide a factory to make SPA nodes"
        module.version = "1.0.5"

Module #11
    Nom : libpipewire-module-client-node
    Paramètre : 
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-client-node"
        object.id = "11"
        object.serial = "11"
        module.author = "Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>"
        module.description = "Allow clients to create and control remote nodes"
        module.version = "1.0.5"

Module #13
    Nom : libpipewire-module-client-device
    Paramètre : 
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-client-device"
        object.id = "13"
        object.serial = "13"
        module.author = "Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>"
        module.description = "Allow clients to create and control remote devices"
        module.version = "1.0.5"

Module #15
    Nom : libpipewire-module-portal
    Paramètre : 
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-portal"
        object.id = "15"
        object.serial = "15"

Module #16
    Nom : libpipewire-module-access
    Paramètre : {
            # Socket-specific access permissions
            #access.socket = { pipewire-0 = "default", pipewire-0-manager = "unrestricted" }

            # Deprecated legacy mode (not socket-based),
            # for now enabled by default if access.socket is not specified
            #access.legacy = true
        }
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-access"
        object.id = "16"
        object.serial = "16"
        module.author = "Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>"
        module.description = "Perform access check"
        module.usage = "( access.socket={ <socket>=<access>, ... } ) ( access.legacy=true ) "
        module.version = "1.0.5"

Module #17
    Nom : libpipewire-module-adapter
    Paramètre : 
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-adapter"
        object.id = "17"
        object.serial = "17"
        module.author = "Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>"
        module.description = "Manage adapter nodes"
        module.version = "1.0.5"

Module #19
    Nom : libpipewire-module-link-factory
    Paramètre : 
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-link-factory"
        object.id = "19"
        object.serial = "19"
        module.author = "Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>"
        module.description = "Allow clients to create links"
        module.usage = "( allow.link.passive=<bool, default false> ) "
        module.version = "1.0.5"

Module #21
    Nom : libpipewire-module-session-manager
    Paramètre : 
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-session-manager"
        object.id = "21"
        object.serial = "21"
        module.author = "George Kiagiadakis <george.kiagiadakis@collabora.com>"
        module.description = "Implements objects for session management"
        module.version = "1.0.5"

Module #28
    Nom : libpipewire-module-jackdbus-detect
    Paramètre : {
            #jack.library     = libjack.so.0
            #jack.server      = null
            #jack.client-name = PipeWire
            #jack.connect     = true
            #tunnel.mode      = duplex  # source|sink|duplex
            source.props = {
                #audio.channels = 2
        #midi.ports = 1
                #audio.position = [ FL FR ]
                # extra sink properties
            }
            sink.props = {
                #audio.channels = 2
        #midi.ports = 1
                #audio.position = [ FL FR ]
                # extra sink properties
            }
        }
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.name = "libpipewire-module-jackdbus-detect"
        object.id = "28"
        object.serial = "28"

Module #536870912
    Nom : module-always-sink
    Paramètre : 
    Nombre d’utilisations : n/d
    Propriétés : 
        module.author = "Pauli Virtanen <pav@iki.fi>"
        module.description = "Always keeps at least one sink loaded even if it's a null one"
        module.usage = "sink_name=<name of sink>"
        module.version = "1.0.5"

Destination #126
    État : IDLE
    Nom : alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo
    Description : HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    Pilote : PipeWire
    Spécification de l’échantillon : s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Plan des canaux : front-left,front-right
    Module du propriétaire : 4294967295
    Sourdine : non
    Volume : front-left: 29491 /  45% / -20,81 dB,   front-right: 29491 /  45% / -20,81 dB
            balance 0,00
    Volume de base : 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Source du moniteur : alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor
    Latence : 0 usec, configuré 0 usec
    Marqueurs : HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
    Propriétés :
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10de0094,14628d92,00100100"
        alsa.device = "3"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.id = "NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xef080000 irq 17"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia GPU 94 HDMI/DP"
        alsa.name = "DELL U2718Q"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA NVidia at 0xef080000 irq 17"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HDA NVidia"
        api.alsa.path = "hdmi:0"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "0"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "4"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.id = "48"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.routes = "1"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        device.description = "HDA NVidia"
        node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo"
        node.nick = "DELL U2718Q"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:0:hdmi:0:playback"
        priority.driver = "696"
        priority.session = "696"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "35"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "merge"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "79"
        object.serial = "126"
        node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
        api.alsa.period-size = "1024"
        api.alsa.period-num = "32"
        api.alsa.headroom = "0"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "0"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1"
        device.nick = "HDA NVidia"
        device.plugged.usec = "7069916"
        device.product.id = "0x10fa"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.vendor.id = "0x10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.string = "0"
    Ports :
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, availability group: Legacy 1, available)
    Port actif : hdmi-output-0
    Formats :
        pcm

Destination #146
    État : RUNNING
    Nom : alsa_output.usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00.analog-stereo
    Description : EPOS BTD 800 Analog Stereo
    Pilote : PipeWire
    Spécification de l’échantillon : s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Plan des canaux : front-left,front-right
    Module du propriétaire : 4294967295
    Sourdine : non
    Volume : front-left: 26214 /  40% / -23,88 dB,   front-right: 26214 /  40% / -23,88 dB
            balance 0,00
    Volume de base : 41335 /  63% / -12,01 dB
    Source du moniteur : alsa_output.usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latence : 0 usec, configuré 0 usec
    Marqueurs : HARDWARE HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Propriétés :
        alsa.card = "3"
        alsa.card_name = "EPOS BTD 800"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.components = "USB1395:0382"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        alsa.id = "E800"
        alsa.long_card_name = "EPOS EPOS BTD 800 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, full speed"
        alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "EPOS EPOS BTD 800 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, full speed"
        api.alsa.card.name = "EPOS BTD 800"
        api.alsa.path = "front:3"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "3"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "3"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.id = "84"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.routes = "1"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        device.description = "EPOS BTD 800"
        node.name = "alsa_output.usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "EPOS BTD 800"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:3:front:3:playback"
        priority.driver = "1009"
        priority.session = "1009"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "35"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "merge"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "86"
        object.serial = "146"
        node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
        api.alsa.period-size = "256"
        api.alsa.period-num = "128"
        api.alsa.headroom = "256"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "3"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio3"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.bus-id = "usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-usb"
        device.name = "alsa_card.usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00"
        device.nick = "EPOS BTD 800"
        device.plugged.usec = "2794502964"
        device.product.id = "0x0382"
        device.product.name = "EPOS BTD 800"
        device.serial = "EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/sound/card3"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1395"
        device.vendor.name = "DSEA A/S"
        device.string = "3"
    Ports :
        analog-output: Analog Output (type: Analog, priority: 9900, availability unknown)
    Port actif : analog-output
    Formats :
        pcm

Source #62
    État : RUNNING
    Nom : alsa_input.usb-046d_0809_78AC8FE2-02.mono-fallback
    Description : Webcam Pro 9000 Mono
    Pilote : PipeWire
    Spécification de l’échantillon : s16le 1ch 48000Hz
    Plan des canaux : mono
    Module du propriétaire : 4294967295
    Sourdine : non
    Volume : mono: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Volume de base : 19944 /  30% / -31,00 dB
    Moniteur de la destination : n/d
    Latence : 0 usec, configuré 0 usec
    Marqueurs : HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Propriétés :
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x809"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.components = "USB046d:0809"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        alsa.id = "U0x46d0x809"
        alsa.long_card_name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x809 at usb-0000:00:14.0-5, high speed"
        alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "USB Device 0x46d:0x809 at usb-0000:00:14.0-5, high speed"
        api.alsa.card.name = "USB Device 0x46d:0x809"
        api.alsa.path = "hw:1"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "1"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "capture"
        audio.channels = "1"
        audio.position = "MONO"
        card.profile.device = "1"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.id = "49"
        device.profile.description = "Mono"
        device.profile.name = "mono-fallback"
        device.routes = "1"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.source"
        media.class = "Audio/Source"
        device.description = "Webcam Pro 9000"
        node.name = "alsa_input.usb-046d_0809_78AC8FE2-02.mono-fallback"
        node.nick = "USB Device 0x46d 0x809"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:1:hw:1:capture"
        priority.driver = "2000"
        priority.session = "2000"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "35"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "split"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "62"
        object.serial = "62"
        node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
        api.alsa.period-size = "512"
        api.alsa.period-num = "64"
        api.alsa.headroom = "512"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "1"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.bus-id = "usb-046d_0809_78AC8FE2-02"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:5:1.2"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.form_factor = "webcam"
        device.icon_name = "camera-web-analog-usb"
        device.name = "alsa_card.usb-046d_0809_78AC8FE2-02"
        device.nick = "USB Device 0x46d:0x809"
        device.plugged.usec = "7635131"
        device.product.id = "0x0809"
        device.product.name = "Webcam Pro 9000"
        device.serial = "046d_0809_78AC8FE2"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.2/sound/card1"
        device.vendor.id = "0x046d"
        device.vendor.name = "Logitech, Inc."
        device.string = "1"
    Ports :
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, availability unknown)
    Port actif : analog-input-mic
    Formats :
        pcm

Source #126
    État : IDLE
    Nom : alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor
    Description : Monitor of HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    Pilote : PipeWire
    Spécification de l’échantillon : s32le 2ch 48000Hz
    Plan des canaux : front-left,front-right
    Module du propriétaire : 4294967295
    Sourdine : non
    Volume : front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Volume de base : 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Moniteur de la destination : alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo
    Latence : 0 usec, configuré 0 usec
    Marqueurs : HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Propriétés :
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10de0094,14628d92,00100100"
        alsa.device = "3"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        alsa.id = "NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xef080000 irq 17"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia GPU 94 HDMI/DP"
        alsa.name = "DELL U2718Q"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA NVidia at 0xef080000 irq 17"
        api.alsa.card.name = "HDA NVidia"
        api.alsa.path = "hdmi:0"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "0"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "4"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "monitor"
        device.id = "48"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.routes = "1"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        device.description = "HDA NVidia"
        node.name = "alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo"
        node.nick = "DELL U2718Q"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:0:hdmi:0:playback"
        priority.driver = "696"
        priority.session = "696"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "35"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "merge"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "79"
        object.serial = "126"
        node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
        api.alsa.period-size = "1024"
        api.alsa.period-num = "32"
        api.alsa.headroom = "0"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "0"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
        device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1"
        device.nick = "HDA NVidia"
        device.plugged.usec = "7069916"
        device.product.id = "0x10fa"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.vendor.id = "0x10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.string = "0"
    Ports :
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, availability group: Legacy 1, available)
    Port actif : hdmi-output-0
    Formats :
        pcm

Source #146
    État : RUNNING
    Nom : alsa_output.usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00.analog-stereo.monitor
    Description : Monitor of EPOS BTD 800 Analog Stereo
    Pilote : PipeWire
    Spécification de l’échantillon : s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Plan des canaux : front-left,front-right
    Module du propriétaire : 4294967295
    Sourdine : non
    Volume : front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Volume de base : 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Moniteur de la destination : alsa_output.usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00.analog-stereo
    Latence : 0 usec, configuré 0 usec
    Marqueurs : HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Propriétés :
        alsa.card = "3"
        alsa.card_name = "EPOS BTD 800"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.components = "USB1395:0382"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        alsa.id = "E800"
        alsa.long_card_name = "EPOS EPOS BTD 800 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, full speed"
        alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "EPOS EPOS BTD 800 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, full speed"
        api.alsa.card.name = "EPOS BTD 800"
        api.alsa.path = "front:3"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "3"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "playback"
        audio.channels = "2"
        audio.position = "FL,FR"
        card.profile.device = "3"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "monitor"
        device.id = "84"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.routes = "1"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.sink"
        media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        device.description = "EPOS BTD 800"
        node.name = "alsa_output.usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00.analog-stereo"
        node.nick = "EPOS BTD 800"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:3:front:3:playback"
        priority.driver = "1009"
        priority.session = "1009"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "35"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "merge"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "86"
        object.serial = "146"
        node.max-latency = "16384/48000"
        api.alsa.period-size = "256"
        api.alsa.period-num = "128"
        api.alsa.headroom = "256"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "3"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio3"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.bus-id = "usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-usb"
        device.name = "alsa_card.usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00"
        device.nick = "EPOS BTD 800"
        device.plugged.usec = "2794502964"
        device.product.id = "0x0382"
        device.product.name = "EPOS BTD 800"
        device.serial = "EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/sound/card3"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1395"
        device.vendor.name = "DSEA A/S"
        device.string = "3"
    Ports :
        analog-output: Analog Output (type: Analog, priority: 9900, availability unknown)
    Port actif : analog-output
    Formats :
        pcm

Source #147
    État : RUNNING
    Nom : alsa_input.usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00.mono-fallback
    Description : EPOS BTD 800 Mono
    Pilote : PipeWire
    Spécification de l’échantillon : s16le 1ch 16000Hz
    Plan des canaux : mono
    Module du propriétaire : 4294967295
    Sourdine : non
    Volume : mono: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Volume de base : 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Moniteur de la destination : n/d
    Latence : 0 usec, configuré 0 usec
    Marqueurs : HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Propriétés :
        alsa.card = "3"
        alsa.card_name = "EPOS BTD 800"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.components = "USB1395:0382"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        alsa.id = "E800"
        alsa.long_card_name = "EPOS EPOS BTD 800 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, full speed"
        alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        api.alsa.card.longname = "EPOS EPOS BTD 800 at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, full speed"
        api.alsa.card.name = "EPOS BTD 800"
        api.alsa.path = "hw:3"
        api.alsa.pcm.card = "3"
        api.alsa.pcm.stream = "capture"
        audio.channels = "1"
        audio.position = "MONO"
        card.profile.device = "2"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.id = "84"
        device.profile.description = "Mono"
        device.profile.name = "mono-fallback"
        device.routes = "1"
        factory.name = "api.alsa.pcm.source"
        media.class = "Audio/Source"
        device.description = "EPOS BTD 800"
        node.name = "alsa_input.usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00.mono-fallback"
        node.nick = "EPOS BTD 800"
        node.pause-on-idle = "false"
        object.path = "alsa:pcm:3:hw:3:capture"
        priority.driver = "2000"
        priority.session = "2000"
        factory.id = "18"
        clock.quantum-limit = "8192"
        client.id = "35"
        node.driver = "true"
        factory.mode = "split"
        audio.adapt.follower = ""
        library.name = "audioconvert/libspa-audioconvert"
        object.id = "88"
        object.serial = "147"
        node.max-latency = "16000/16000"
        api.alsa.period-size = "256"
        api.alsa.period-num = "125"
        api.alsa.headroom = "256"
        api.acp.auto-port = "false"
        api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
        api.alsa.card = "3"
        api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
        api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio3"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.bus-id = "usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.0"
        device.enum.api = "udev"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-usb"
        device.name = "alsa_card.usb-EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583-00"
        device.nick = "EPOS BTD 800"
        device.plugged.usec = "2794502964"
        device.product.id = "0x0382"
        device.product.name = "EPOS BTD 800"
        device.serial = "EPOS_EPOS_BTD_800_A000870205107583"
        device.subsystem = "sound"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/sound/card3"
        device.vendor.id = "0x1395"
        device.vendor.name = "DSEA A/S"
        device.string = "3"
    Ports :
        analog-input-headset-mic: Headset Microphone (type: Casque, priority: 8800, availability unknown)
    Port actif : analog-input-headset-mic
    Formats :
        pcm


Isn't pavucontrol for pulseaudio, not pipewire?

Yes indeed. I think it is working through the pipewire-pulseaudio bridge. However when I upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04 (and thus from pulseaudio to pipewire), it did not install what would be the equivalent for pipewire (and which I do not know). A quick search ion the internet indicated that this seems to be what people do.

Investigating why pipewire-session-manager.service was reported as Loaded: error (Reason: Unit pipewire-session-manager.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists), I stumbled upon an earlier question that may be related.
Although things (notably package names) seems to have changed since then, I tried the accepted answer :
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio

I do not have the slightest idea what this actually does, but today plugging in the USB dongle for my EPOS headset causes the system to automatically switch to it, and unplugging causes it to switch back to the GPU output.
